# Using bookdown, can I add tag to <body>?

Tags: html, tags, bookdown

In the bookdown manual, I read (https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/yaml-options.html):

> The `includes` option allows you to insert arbitrary custom content before and/or after the body of the output. It has three sub-options: `in_header`, `before_body`, and `after_body`

This is fine; I have used these hooks before.

But what if I want something like this?

```
<body onload="checkEdits()">
```

For context, I am trying to implement the ideas on this page: https://www.developerdrive.com/allowing-users-to-edit-text-content-with-html5/

The idea is that students can "answer" some questions in their online book, and the text remains when they return. Since I'm not really sure what I'm doing, maybe there are other/better ways...  I may be implementing things poorly anyway.

P.